# How to convert Linq array[] to int[]?

Tags: linq

I've got a Linq query against a DataRow[] that returns elements from each row. Looks a bit like this:

```
var query = from row in rows select row["Id"];
```

I want to convert this into an int[], but the following code generates an error:

```
int[] myIntArray = query.ToArray();
```

The error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type object[] to int[]
```

Is there some clever trick for making this work?

Answer (score 8):

The `DataRow` indexer (`row[...]`) returns `object`, not `int`.
Therefore, your implicitly-typed query is a set of `object`s.

You need to explicitly select `int`s, like this:

```
int[] numbers = rows.Select(r => r.Field<int>("Id")).ToArray();
```

(or just `select (int)row["Id"]`)

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized that the conversion was allowable inside the Linq query itself. Very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.  LINQ queries can have arbitrary expressions.